# How to operate functions of component controllers from outside

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I have a component with a function inside:

```
app.component("myComponent", {
    templateUrl: "myComponent.html",
    controller: function() {
        this.addApp = function (arg) {
            console.log(arg);
        };
    }
})
```

I would like to operate that function from outside the component:

```
<my-component>
</my-component>

<button type="button" ng-click="something.addApp('Cheese')"
        class="btn-sm btn-default no-modal" >
  Add Application
</button>
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access functions of component controllers, use the [`ng-ref`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRef) directive:

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl as vm">
    <my-component ng-ref="vm.myComponent1">
    </my-component>

    <button type="button" ng-click="vm.myComponent1.addApp('Cheese')"
            class="btn-sm btn-default no-modal" >
      Add Application
    </button>
</div>
```

The ng-ref directive tells AngularJS to assign the controller of a component (or a directive) to the given property in the current scope.

If the element with `ng-ref` is destroyed `null` is assigned to the property.

Note that if you want to assign from a child into the parent scope, you must initialize the target property on the parent scope, otherwise `ng-ref` will assign on the child scope. This commonly happens when assigning elements or components wrapped in `ng-if` or `ng-repeat`.

Instantiating controllers with "controllerAs" syntax obviates that problem.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-ref Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRef)

**Note:** The `ng-ref` directive was added to [AngularJS V1.7.1 Momentum-Defiance](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#user-content-171-momentum-defiance-2018-06-08)